# Audio slider doesn't change value

Tags: unity, c#, scripting, audio, ui-design

For some reason, my slider and audio resets back to 0 when I stop and play the game after I changed the value. Here is the code, I can't spot anything wrong with it:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MainAudio : MonoBehaviour {

public Slider slider;

void Awake()
{
    PlayerPrefs.Save ();
    GetComponent<AudioSource> ().volume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("CurVol");
    if (slider)
    slider.value = GetComponent<AudioSource> ().volume;
}
public void VolumeControl(float volumeControl)
{
    GetComponent<AudioSource> ().volume = volumeControl;
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("CurVol", GetComponent<AudioSource> ().volume);
    PlayerPrefs.Save ();
}
}
```

Comment: There is no statement that calls `VolumeControl`, you also only set the slider value at the beginning. Remember that `AudioSource.volume` is a float which is a value type.

Comment: I'm a beginner, So how do I fix it?

Comment: The mistakes you made are basic object oriented learning gaps. Learn about reference types and value types and their differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Update` method to update the current volume.

```
private void Update()
{
    VolumeControl(slider.value);
}
```

And use the `OnApplicationQuit` method to save your current volume to the PlayerPrefs.
Receiving the saved volume from the PlayerPrefs in the `Awake` method can be done like in your code snippet, but without the `PlayerPrefs.Save` statement.